# how do I open files using an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, fopen

I want to open file named `ex1, ex2, ex3 ...exn` etc.
Now when i put the value of `n` like, `n=1, ex1` will be opened 
for, `n=2, ex2` file will be opened and then I will read or write my c program output array from or into it.
can the name of the file be given as a string?

As I am new with programing please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes you can. But you should read some book about C programming first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you open a file you use the function `fopen`

```
fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    exit(1); // Or you can raise some error code and return if this code is in a function.       
}
// Process the file
```

Now in your case, you need to manipulate the filename. So you can take a C string for this.

```
char filename[10];

// N is set from code above

sprintf(filename,"ex%d",N);
fp = fopen (filename, "w+");

// Further behaviour is same
```

Comment: Thank you very  much. I did according to what you have told. Here is the code that I have written:
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fr;
char filename[10];
int i;
printf("enter the number of file");
scanf("%d", &i);
sprintf(filename, "exx%d", i);
fr=fopen(filename, "w");
fprintf(fr, "%d", 20);
fclose(fr);
return 0;
}

Here a file named exx1 or exx2 is been created after running the program.

But what i want is that I want to read or write in a file which is already generated as exx1.txt , exx2 or exx3.

what modification do i need to do for that?

Comment: Then you need `"exx%d.txt"`. But be careful, your filename variable only has 10 bytes and one of them must be 0. So n=100 would cause a buffer overflow unless you make filename larger.